# retrieving the last pending order of a customer

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have some `Order`s created by `Customers` stored in `postgres` db.Some of the Orders may have `'pending'` status.I want the user to be able to work on his last pending Order.

order table

```
id   | order_num | order_date |customer_id | status
-----+-----------+------------+------------+---------
80   | 1234      | 02-01-2000 | 20         | pending
----------------------------------------------------
81   | 2345      | 02-01-2000 |20          | confirmed
-----------------------------------------------------
82   | 3456      | 02-01-2000 |20          | pending
--------------------------------------------------
83   | 3498      | 02-001-2000|  20        | confirmed
----------------------------------------------------
```

Is there anything wrong with using

```
select * from orders where customer_id =20 and status='pending' order by id DESC limit 1
```

The order_date for multiple records may be same.The order number may not always be in ascending order. Is ordering by id safe in this regards?

Comment: How about ordering based on `order_num`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order by the `order_date` with `id` as a secondary sort key:

```
select *
from orders
where customer_id = 20
  and status      = 'pending'
order by order_date desc, id desc
limit 1
```

You want the most recent order so you should sort to express that intent. You also have to deal with duplicate `order_date` values so you can throw `id` in as a secondary sort key to, hopefully, get the most recent one on the most recent `order_date`. This assumes that `id` is a `serial` or `bigserial` column.

You're probably safe using `order by id desc` as long as the `order_date` is not allowed to change after the record is created. However, if you `order by order_date desc, id desc` then it will be immediately obvious what your intent is, the people maintaining your code (possibly you) might appreciate it when you saying exactly what you mean.

Comment: that is good advice.Still,I am wondering if sorting based entirely on id has any pitfalls?

Comment: @Damon: The only pitfall is that `order_date` might be changed. Most likely it doesn't change and `id` is based on a sequence, if so then `id` is pretty much the "order of insertion" so `order by id desc` would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Top-N-Analysis and Find the top most record with respect to date and status

Comment: as I said ,several records may have the same order_date